# How to create a function which eliminates repeated code

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have the following code in my `Page_Load` function:

```
string[] strArrayForEntity;
string[] strArrayForLocation;
string[] strArrayForSpecialty;
int inCounter;
inCounter = 0;

strArrayForEntity = new string[Entity.Items.Count];
foreach (ListItem li in Entity.Items)
{
    strArrayForEntity[inCounter] = li.Value;
    inCounter++;
}

inCounter = 0;
strArrayForLocation = new string[Location.Items.Count];
foreach (ListItem li in Location.Items)
{
    strArrayForLocation[inCounter] = li.Value;
    inCounter++;
}

inCounter = 0;
strArrayForSpecialty = new string[Specialty.Items.Count];
foreach (ListItem li in Specialty.Items)
{
    strArrayForSpecialty[inCounter] = li.Value;
    inCounter++;
}
```

As you can see I am repeating the same thing with the exception of the array name and the dropdownlist ID.

I wanted to make a function where I can feed the array name and the dropdownlist so I don't have to have repeated code. I tried the following:

```
public void AddTooArray(string[] strArrayName, DropDownList strID)
{
    inCounter = 0;
    foreach (ListItem li in strID.Items)
    {
        strArrayName = li.Value;
        inCounter++;
    }
}
```

I was planning on calling it like this: `AddToArray(strArrayForEntity, Entity);`

I am getting the error in this line: `strArrayName = li.value`;
Error: `Cannot implicitly  convert type 'string' to 'string[]'`

Can I resolve the issue?

Test code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    strArrayForEntity = new string[Entity.Items.Count]; //count is 1 (2 entries in the dropdownlist)
    AddToArray(strArrayForEntity, Entity);
    MessageBox.Show(strArrayForEntity.Length.toString()); //displays 0
}
public void AddToArray(string[] strArrayName, DropDownList strID)
{
    inCounter = 0;
    foreach (ListItem li in strID.Items)
    {
        strArrayName[inCounter] = li.Value;
        inCounter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use LINQ:

```
string[] strArrayForEntity = Entity.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Value).ToArray();
```

Notice that `ListItemCollection` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so you need to add explicit `Cast<ListItem>()`.

Comment: I get this error: `'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge add `using System.Linq;` to make `Select` extension method available.

Comment: I have `using System.Linq;` on top of my page.

Comment: that's not the problem. `ListItemCollection` does not implement `IEnumerable<T> ` you need `Entity.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Value).ToArray();`

Comment: That works but I am getting `0` but the dropdownlist has two entries.

Comment: @Selman22 right, I've updated my answer. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: This is what I have in page_load: `string[] strArrayForEntity2 = Entity.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Value).ToArray(); MessageBox.Show(strArrayForEntity2.Length.ToString()); //displays 0`

Comment: Ok nevermind. I was calling the function which populates the dropdownlist AFTER the code. I moved it to the top and it works!!! Thanks. Silly me.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot your array indexer.

```
strArrayName[inCounter] = li.Value;
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh... It was that simple? :/

Comment: Happens to everyone, mate!

Comment: The answer is correct, but you must be sure that the array has been setted before to call your method "AddTooArray".

Comment: I ended up using @sergeys solution as it was simpler. I did +1 your post as it did help in my function. Thanks so much for your response.